# Handling errors in SYNC handler

Tags: google-smart-home

I am interested in the best practice for handling errors in the Google Action `SYNC` handler.

I [see in the docs](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/reference/intent/sync) that I can return an `errorCode` in the `SYNC` response, however, none of the [documented error codes](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/reference/errors-exceptions#error_list) seem to be compatible with the `SYNC` handler, only `QUERY`, `EXECUTE`, etc.

I see that the SYNC response must contain a `userAgentId` or the Action service deems it an invalid response, however, what happens when I am unable to authenticate the user and I am unable to determine and ID for them?

In that case, should I simply provide an empty string for that property?

Should I just response with an empty object `{}` in the response when I encounter an error?

Any info is helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Of all the listed error codes, not all of them may make sense but some like `relinkRequired` could be useful.

More specifically for you, in the case that the authentication process fails that error should come from the OAuth link. Your [account linking](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/concepts/account-linking), when presented with an incorrect user, should fail at that point and not proceed with sending a `SYNC` response.